# How to find a Type that inherits from some BaseClass

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, reflection, .net-assembly

I have a class

```
public class BaseClass
{

}
```

I have a child class

```
public class ChildClass : BaseClass
{

}
```

I want to know what classes/types inherit from BaseClass (find ChildClass for example). I know that i have to use assemble and reflection but don't know how/which function to use.

Edit: ok maybe now you'll get it

Comment: me not understand your question

Comment: Are the two classes in the same assembly? Do you need to be able to find further derived classes, or just direct children?

Comment: What's question here? What's the issue with using reflection?

Comment: (regarding B001's comment, they're saying that your English is not correct)

Comment: @user202729 no you are wrong! I am telling him (in his language) that I dont understand his question... and nobody had asked you for interpreting my comment

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
typeof(BaseClass).Assembly.GetTypes().Where(type => type.IsSubclassOf(typeof(A)));
```

You can do this by two step:

1. Get all types from Assembly
2. Find only classes which is subclasses of BaseClass

Comment: Thx you, @B001ᛦ

Comment: wont get all subtypes (as could be in a separate assembly) but best i think we will get +1